# How to assign total row count into a variable and use while selecting rand?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the row count, get the percentage of it and want to assign it into a variable named percentage. Then I will use the data for selecting COUNT%10 random rows from table.

Is there any way to do this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/10 AS co 
FROM table
```

puts it into a row but i want the row data and use it.

Comment: I think that you need to use a SELECT .. INTO clause for that

Comment: @TheRandomForest no, it's not what i want to do. I will select 10% random rows from total number of rows on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will select 10% random rows from total number of rows on the table.

Use analytic functions and order by a random value:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE ) AS rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_rows
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn <= total_rows / 10;
```

Or, from Oracle 12, you can use `FETCH FIRST 10 PERCENT ROWS ONLY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
FETCH FIRST 10 PERCENT ROWS ONLY
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, col1, col2 ) AS
SELECT LEVEL,
       CHR( LEVEL + 32 ),
       DATE '1970-01-01' + ( LEVEL - 1 )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 80;
```

May output the random rows:

> ```
> ID | COL1 | COL2     
> -: | :--- | :--------
> 69 | e    | 10-MAR-70
> 29 | =    | 29-JAN-70
> 17 | 1    | 17-JAN-70
> 54 | V    | 23-FEB-70
> 73 | i    | 14-MAR-70
> 46 | N    | 15-FEB-70
> 37 | E    | 06-FEB-70
>  1 | !    | 01-JAN-70
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2833d846a24acd33b630863961ef4575)*

Comment: @LunaAquila . . . This actually correctly answers the question that you asked.  Littlefoot's answer is fine, but it does not return *random* rows.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this help? (selecting 30%, though; `EMP` table is small)

```
SQL> select * from emp
  2  where rownum < (select count(*) * 0.3 from emp);

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.1980 00:00:00        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.1981 00:00:00       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.1981 00:00:00       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.1981 00:00:00       2975                    20

SQL>
```

Comment: This will not get random rows (While result sets are theoretically unordered; in practice, Oracle will return result sets in the order that the rows are read from the data files and this means that you are highly likely to always get the same set of rows returned every time.)

Comment: Yes, I agree. My *lucky guess* was that ANY rows that come into desired percentage would do. Depending on what happens to that table (frequent deletes/inserts), lucky guess might return more "random" data set.